# Waiting for Process Response

Tags: c#, process

So in my application I am starting up a new process. I have redirected the standard in, standard out, and the standard error to a StreamWriter and StreamReaders respectively.

Now I want to act accordingly to how the process responds in either its standard out or standard error, and I was wondering if there was a better way of doing that than putting my project to sleep like this:

```
p = Process.start(some.exe);
StreamWriter process_si = p.StandardInput;
StreamReader process_so = p.StandardOutput;
StreamReader process_se = p.StandardError;

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
if(process.HasExited)
{
   Read standard Error...
}

else
{
   read the standard input...
}
```

My idea would be to do something like this:

```
p = Process.start(some.exe);
StreamWriter process_si = p.StandardInput;
StreamReader process_so = p.StandardOutput;
StreamReader process_se = p.StandardError;

// Wait fro some type of response from the process
p.waitForStandardErrorOrStarndardOut();

if(process_se contains message)
{
   Read standard Error...
}

else if(process_so contains message)
{
   read the standard input...
}
```

Is there any simple way to wait for a response. My best guess for this is to create my own waiting for response function that looks like this:

```
void waitForResponse(StreamReader errorOut, StreamReader standardOut)
{
   while(errorOut.isEmpty() && standardOut.isEmpty())
   {
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
   }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions. I have found some other threads similar to mine but didn't answer my question completely...

Comment: I think you can just read stdin and stderr to the end. That should block your program until the process has either closed both streams explicitly (which you, I assume, don't do), or until it has exited. (This was assuming that the child is a one-shot.)

Comment: Peter's idea sounds great.  Do you have access to the source code for the application you're running?  (In other words, there is a sure fire and efficient way to wait for that process to end; however, it would require a slight modification to the process you're spawning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use asynchronous reads to the output and error streams as explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginerrorreadline(v=vs.110).aspx).
And then put the main thread to sleep with the [WaitForExit()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

So in code that would be:

```
void main()
{
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("fileName.exe", "<arguments>");
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

    var p = Process.Start(psi);
    p.OutputDataReceived += p_OutputDataReceived;
    p.ErrorDataReceived += p_ErrorDataReceived;
    p.WaitForExit();
}
static void p_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //react on the received error data in e.Data.
}

static void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //react on the received output data in e.Data.
}
```